# Making an Information Box Fly Out and Expand

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick

I am trying to make a circle that, when clicked, causes a box with text to fly out and expand. Then, when clicked again, I want the box to collapse and become invisible again. I've included my code. I got the box to fly out, but I cannot seem to get it to collapse. Please help.

HTML/Javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="indexstyle.css">
<title>
</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id ="container">
<div id ="circle" onclick = "expand();">
<div id ="info">
Information will go here
</div>
</div>
</div>

<script>
var expanded = 0;
function expand(){
if (expanded == 0){
var info = document.getElementById("info");
var circle = document.getElementById("circle");
info.style.zIndex = 1;
info.style.margin = "300px";
info.style.width = "500px";
info.style.padding = "50px";
info.style.visibility = "visible";
info.style.height = auto;
info.style.zIndex = "-1";
expanded = 1;
return expanded;
}
else {
info.style.margin = "0";
}
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
#container {
position: relative;
width: 100%;
padding-bottom: 100%;
}

#circle {
position: absolute;
width: 10%;
height: 10%;
background-color: blue;
border-radius: 50%;
}

#info{
word-wrap: break-word;
margin-top: 25%;
margin-left: 25%;
position: absolute;
width: 15%;
height: 15%;
background-color: #e5e5e5;
border-radius: 25px;
transition: 0.5s;
z-index: -1;
visibility: hidden;
overflow: hidden;
border: solid black 1px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the fiddle. I removed the CSS from the JavaScript and simply swapped the className on the DOM object. It's much easier to read that way.

https://jsfiddle.net/m5ppyw08/

Also, I didn't use jQuery in this example.

HTML:

```
<title>
</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id ="container">
<div id ="circle">
<div id ="info">
Information will go here
</div>
</div>
</div>

<script>
circle.addEventListener('click',expand);
function collapse(e){
    info.className='';
    e.target.removeEventListener('click',collapse);
    e.target.addEventListener('click',expand);
}
function expand(e){
    info.className='expanded';
    e.target.removeEventListener('click',expand);
    e.target.addEventListener('click',collapse);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
position: relative;
width: 100%;
padding-bottom: 100%;
}

#circle {
position: absolute;
width: 10%;
height: 10%;
background-color: blue;
border-radius: 50%;
}

#info{
word-wrap: break-word;
margin-top: 25%;
margin-left: 25%;
position: absolute;
width: 15%;
height: 15%;
background-color: #e5e5e5;
border-radius: 25px;
transition: 0.5s;
z-index: -1;
visibility: hidden;
overflow: hidden;
border: solid black 1px;
}
#info.expanded{
position:absolute;
z-index:-1;
margin:300px;
width:500px;
padding:50px;
visibility:visible;
height:auto;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I was trying to do. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: No problem. Note that you do not need to use document.getElementById(). Any DOM element with an id tag is loaded as a variable with global scope onload. The important thing is making sure you add the script at the end of the document.

Comment: If you are satisfied with the answer, select it as the correct answer :)

Answer (score 0):

mhunt2015 Perhaps this is what you're looking for. I've set this up with jQuery.

The logic behind it is having this "flyout" hidden by default, then utilize a jQuery click event to toggle the class which will display said flyout.

You can check out this **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kwh71787/tmh941sb/)** to get a better understanding

Here is the jQuery I used to control the flyout.

```
$("#circle").click(function(){
    $("#info").toggleClass("active");
});
```

I hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: Thank you very much! That is such a simple solution, and I can't believe I didn't just think about using jQuery!